# *ngIf equivalent in lit-element/polymer

Tags: polymer, lit-element

I'm looking to implement condition based HTML in lit-element and need something like *ngIf which Angular provides.

I could render different HTML based on conditions but it will be great if it can be done with condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use plain Javascript. Explained well in [official documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/try/logic)

Example:

```
${this.myBool ? html`<p>something</p>` : html`<p>something else</p>`}
```

Comment: Thanks Kuba. I'm already doing this and wondered if this is the best approach?

Comment: definitely is. Lit element is all about JS literals (in templates). So using them is best approach

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Kuba's answer, it's good to be as specific as possible with lit-html conditions, as the more broad-scoped your condition is, the more of the template that needs to be rerendered when the condition changes.  For example, you can make the example given in the [official documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/try/logic):

```
this.myBool ? html`<p>something</p>` : html`<p>something else</p>`
```

And write it more efficiently as:

```
html`<p>${this.myBool ? 'something' : 'something else'}</p>`
```

This little change here doesn't change much, but when you can reduce the amount of rerendering of layers of components, it starts to add up.

For a more thorough explanation of how `lit-html` handles template rendering, see: https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/concepts#template-creation